# How to create a snippet containing all lines with a mark in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I would like to add certain lines of code to the doxygen documentation without duplicating them. I would rather mark them with a string in the comment, like

```
if (some1 > SOME1_MAX) return ERROR_SOME1_TOO_BIG;//include_in_doxy
//.. other code here ...
if (some2 > SOME2_MAX) return ERROR_SOME2_TOO_BIG;//include_in_doxy
```

and include them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I do understand the question completely, when not the case please add a bit more of a detail, but did you have a look at the \snippet command?

Comment: Yes. \snippet allows one snippet in the file (it warns if there are more) . \dontinclude would need \line \skip..., basically a little program which would need to fit to the code exactly. Instead I'd like included simply all lines with the mark.

Comment: \snippet could be extended to allow same names. But considering the current functionality of \snippet it is unlikely that there is another way to do this. So one needs to make a separate snippet for each line and then make a \snippet command for each such snippet.